# how do you fix expected indented block error in python? I'm using PyCharm

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pycharm, syntax-error

I really don't know how do I fix this error? Since I already hit a tab after my line 4.

This is my code, very simple one:

```
import csv

def searchProxy():

card Identifier = input('Enter proxy\n')
csv_file = csv.reader(open ('\Users\Keanu\Documents\ARRMAIL07072021180029.CSV', 'r'))

for row Card Identifier in csv_file:
    if Card Identifier == row[0]:
            print(row)



print ('Enter to search card identifier')

src = int(input ("Enter here: "))
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Keanu\Documents\PythonProjects\main.py", line 5
    card Identifier = input('Enter proxy\n')
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: There should be 4-space indentation after ```def...()```

Comment: (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/) this link will help you to understand the concept of Indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `def` there should be some indentation. Also, don't use spaces when declaring the variables. Use a `_` if you want to separate the name.

```
def searchProxy():

    card_Identifier = input('Enter proxy\n')
    csv_file = csv.reader(open ('\Users\Keanu\Documents\ARRMAIL07072021180029.CSV', 'r'))

    for row Card Identifier in csv_file:
        if Card Identifier == row[0]:
            print(row)
```

Unlike other programming languages which use `{}` to separate blocks of code, python uses indentation. So one should always keep that in mind when coding in python.

Comment: That's still not syntactically valid.

Comment: `card Identifier = ...`?!

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad @jonrsharpe Thanks

Comment: card identifier is a column name in excel file, sorry

Comment: _Getting_ there... please check the code before posting.

Comment: It's really not!